# Android Studio everytime starts with minimize window size

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio everytime running with minimize window size instead of full screen. How fix it?

[image]

Comment: same for me, really annoying, have you found a solution?

Comment: @j2esu try with new solution

Comment: Still trying to find a solution, is annoying Android studio open in window mode instead maximized.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed that problem too.
It's bug of android Studio version 4.0 to 4.1.
On 3.6.3 or Canary 4.2 window opens maximized as desired for me.

Comment: My version is 4.1.2 and still has the same problem.

Comment: Confirmed that v4.1.2 still has same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have Android Studio 4.1 on Windows 10.
I did fix this in two ways:

**First:**
By making own simple plugin (IntelliJ Platform SDK):

*plugin.xml*

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
<postStartupActivity implementation="com.user.PluginBootstrapper"/>
</extensions>
```

*PluginBootstrapper.java*

```
package com.user;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.openapi.startup.StartupActivity;
import com.intellij.openapi.startup.StartupActivity.DumbAware;
import com.intellij.openapi.wm.WindowManager;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class PluginBootstrapper implements StartupActivity, DumbAware {   
    public PluginBootstrapper() { }

    public void runActivity(@NotNull Project project) {
        if (project != null && !project.isDisposed()) {
            JFrame frame = WindowManager.getInstance().getFrame(project);
            if (frame != null) {
                //frame.setLocationRelativeTo((Component)null);
                frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Second:**
Also I have problems with Fonts.

- I changed Android Studio Java runtime from OpenJDK to Oracle JDK.
- Then get plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7698-window-decorate-mode-switcher
- And enable Other Settings -> Swith decorate mode -> Auto undecorate on start

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by doing this:

1- Click android studio on task bar to select

2- Type in CNTR + ALT + S to open setting

3- Install plugin Windows Decorate mode switcher

4- Restart android studio

5 - Press ALT + V and click on Switch decorate mode

Working demo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5-DvPjxauk