# Android studio no longer opens project in maimized window

Tags: android-studio, editor, maximize-window

Since a recent Android Studio (or Windows 10?) update, when I open an existing project in Android Studio, the main window is no longer maximized, as it use to be. I cannot find a setting to specify opening a project in a maximized window. A slight but niggling nuisance.
Operating system: Windows 10
Android Studio version: 4.0.1 (Latest at the time of writing)
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Same issue here, were you able to solve it?

Comment: Still unresolved

Comment: Still an issue in v4.1.2

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71197271/11888809

Answer (score 2):

1. install a plugin which named: window-decorate-mode-switcher
2. enable Other Settings -> Swith decorate mode -> Auto undecorate on start

For details, please check the following links:
[Android Studio everytime starts with minimize window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244211/android-studio-everytime-starts-with-minimize-window-size)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, the problem has resolved itself most of the time, so I won't install another plugin at this stage. I'm wondering if the fact that I am using custom,  scaling ,which is quite unusual I think, contributed to the problem.